# Box doesn't center css layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't get the loginfield centered... I'm using bootstrap 3.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6n580ovd/)**

**Here is my css:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
html{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: rgb(125, 126, 125);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e', GradientType=0);
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
}

body{
    font-family:Vollkorn,Georgia,serif;
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
    font-size:24px;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#777;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    width:100%;
}

.main {
    margin:0 auto;
}

#loginfield {

    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;

    margin: 0 auto ;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #222222;

}
```

**and here the html:**

```
 <body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
        <div id="loginfield" class="col-md-6 main">
            {{ Form::open(['route' => 'sessions.store']) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 loginstyle">
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 loginstyle">
            {{ Form::text('username', '') }}
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2 loginstyle">
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 loginstyle">
            {{ Form::password('password', '') }}
         </div>
         </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 loginstyle">
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block loginstyle-button')) }}
        </div>
        </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**jsFiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/6n580ovd/

Can someone tell me what I forgot? Thanks!

Comment: You are hardcoding the position of the login field. You have already given top 300px for login field. If you also give left: some px, then you can middle the login field.

Comment: Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6n580ovd/ @Govan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#loginfield {
/*position: fixed;  remove */
/*top: 300px;remove */
width:300px; /* upgraded*/
margin: 20px auto; /* modify */
border: 2px solid gray;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #222222;
}

body{ background:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6n580ovd/9/

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Now the field is on the very top and left, still not centered...

Comment: @baao i have upgraded my answer. refresh it.

Comment: @baao this version only Horizontal Centered, no Vertical Centered. do you want  H&C Centered?

Answer (score 0):

try this if you still want position absolute/fixed.

```
#loginfield {
    background-color: #222222;
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -155px auto 0 -100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the desired result, too. Do you have an idea without fixed position?